# Why env variables are not created automatically?

Tags: docker

I am referring [this site](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/) to link containers.

> When two containers are linked, Docker will set some environment variables in the target container to enable programmatic discovery of information related to the source container.

This is the line specified in the documentaion. But when i see /etc/hosts i can see entries for both container. But when i run `env` command, i don't see any port mappings specified in that docker site.

Comment: How are you running the `env` command?  Docker will set those variables in the one process started by `docker run`.

Comment: Inside second docker container, i just typed `env`

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me:

```
$ docker run -d --name redis1 redis
0b869d9f5a43e24976beec6c292839ea2c67983012e50893f0b557cd8bc0c3b4
$ docker run --link redis1:redis1 debian env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=c23a30b8618f
REDIS1_PORT=tcp://172.17.0.3:6379
REDIS1_PORT_6379_TCP=tcp://172.17.0.3:6379
REDIS1_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.3
REDIS1_PORT_6379_TCP_PORT=6379
REDIS1_PORT_6379_TCP_PROTO=tcp
REDIS1_NAME=/berserk_nobel/redis1
REDIS1_ENV_REDIS_VERSION=2.8.19
REDIS1_ENV_REDIS_DOWNLOAD_URL=http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-2.8.19.tar.gz
REDIS1_ENV_REDIS_DOWNLOAD_SHA1=3e362f4770ac2fdbdce58a5aa951c1967e0facc8
HOME=/root
```

If you're still having trouble, you need to provide a way we can recreate your problem.